# EditText selecionada ao iniciar activity

Tags: android

Tenho uma EditText e sempre ao iniciar o APP ela fica "selecionada" isto me atrapalha um pouco (com o ponteirinho) como resolver isso ?
[image: e]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um **LinearLayout** "invisível" acima do Editext. Então o foco sairá do seu Editext:

```
<LinearLayout android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="0px" />
```

**EXEMPLO:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Button android:text="@string/button_text"; android:id="@+id/Button01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
        <LinearLayout android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="0px" />
        <EditText android:text="" android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint">
        </EditText>
        <Button android:text="@string/button_text"; android:id="@+id/Button02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```